# Trying to look at values in one column and update value in anotehr column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying create a macro to look at column F and then update Column I all the way down from the first row until the last.

so read column F for SBS and then update the corresponding row on column I with "National"

THis is my code.

```
Dim LastRow As String
    Dim d As String

LastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For d = SBS To LastRow
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("F" & d).Value) Then
        Range("I" & d).Value = "National"
    End If
Next d
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: What is SBS? ..

Comment: What you are trying to achieve can be probably done with an `IF` statement in column I. please explain what is SBS.

Comment: SBS is just the company name

Answer (score 0):

*Here is quick example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each Rng In Sht.Range("F1", Sht.Range("F9999").End(xlUp))

        If Rng.Value = "SBS" Then
            Rng.Cells.Offset(0, 3).Value = "National"
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Made minor changes in your macro in Dim statement for d and if condition. Also not empty condition is not required:-

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim d As Long


    LastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For d = 1 To LastRow
    If  Range("F" & d).Value = "SBS" Then
        Range("I" & d).Value = "National"
    End If
Next d

End Sub
```

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for the suggestion. Now that I think about ii, it makes sense